# How many other files does include affect aside from the one it's in?

Tags: c++, class, include

I'm just learning C++, and I was under the presumption that including something would only affect the file that included it, but I appear to be wrong. My setup is like so:

[image]

If I don't include BaseClass.h in either Main or Subclass (extends BaseClass), I get an seemingly-normal error telling me I can't use BaseClass in Subclass because it doesn't exist. If I include BaseClass.h in Subclass.h, everything works fine. If I don't include BaseClass.h in Subclass.h, but I include it in the main cpp, it also works fine? At first I thought this meant including something in one file included it for the whole project, but I'm not sure about that because BaseClass.cpp included BaseClass.h this whole time and I got an error when it wasn't included in main/Subclass.

Why am I able to interchange inclusion of BaseClass.h between the main cpp and Subclass.h while having it function in both cases? How many files are affected when I include something?

I'm working in Eclipse Neon with a MinGW GCC project, but I'm not sure if that affects the behavior. Here is the source code I'm working with:

The main cpp, ReproProject.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include "Subclass.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Subclass s;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

BaseClass.h

```
#pragma once

class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass();
};
```

BaseClass.cpp

```
#include "BaseClass.h"

BaseClass::BaseClass()
{

}
```

Subclass.h

```
#pragma once

class Subclass: public BaseClass
{
public:
    Subclass() : BaseClass() {}
};
```

Comment: Simplified, you can look at it this way: For each compilation unit, the preprocessor will replace each #include directive with the contents of the included file. When it's done, you have basically one giant source file, containing all the included code. This is then fed to the compiler, which does its job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of `#include` is as if the referenced file's contents completely replace the `#include` statement itself.

Your `Subclass` class is derived from `Baseclass`. The `subclass.h` header file declares `Subclass`, therefore when compiling `subclass.h`, the definition of `Baseclass` must be available.

Except, and this is the key point, you do not exactly compile `subclass.h`. You are compiling `RetroProject.cpp`. This is what your compiler is actually compiling. Or, rather, begins compiling.

Your compiler starts compiling `RetroProject.cpp`, reading the file from its beginning to its end. Each time it encounters a `#include`, the referenced file's contents completely replace the `#include` statement, and the compiler then resumes reading and compiling the code, starting with the `#include`d text. When it sees another `#include`, the process repeats.

So, if you have a `#include "baseclass.h"` in `subclass.h`, then the following happens. When your `RetroProject.cpp` `#include`s `subclass.h`, the contents of `subclass.h` replace the `#include` statement in `RetroProject.cpp`, then, the compiler resumes compiling, it sees another `#include`, and then it replaces that `#include` with the contents of `baseclass.h`.

The compiler then parses `baseclass.h`, which defines the `BaseClass`, and then it compiles the rest of `subclass.h`, which defines `SubClass`, and since `BaseClass` is already defined, there is no issue.

If you explicitly `#include` the `baseclass.h` file in `retroproject.cpp`, then the compiler first replaces that `#include` with the contents of `baseclass.h`, compiles it, defines the `BaseClass`, then the `#include` of the `subclass.h` file gets processed the same away, and, once again, everything that should be defined, is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you include BaseClass.h in SubClass.h and then include SubClass.h in your main cpp it will include BaseClass.h with it. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, that works and was one of the test cases I mentioned in the question, but I'm curious as why I'm _also_ able to include BaseClass.h in the main cpp and still have SubClass function even though it doesn't include BaseClass.